# Is the heredoc syntax "<<END" logically built on "<" (the input redirect operator)?

Tags: bash, shell, redirection

There are various idioms in shell scripting or any programming language that we just don't question.

But given the ingenuity of Doug McIllroy I wonder if there is a deeper reason that `<` and `<<END` look related (e.g. the way redirect output `>` and redirect append output `>>` are logically similar).

Is this syntax arbitrary, or can it be read logically as a compound operation of the redirect input? Put another way, is `<<END` implemented as just a special case of '<'?

(hope my question makes sense)

Comment: The only people who can actually answer this would be the authors of early Unix shells – perhaps on the TUHS mailing list.

Comment: That's true, but a consistent narrative would be an adequate substitute. Basically I'm trying to memorize as little obscure shell syntax as I can and mentally derive the rest.